# CSS div border discrepancy

Tags: html, css

I have a row of horizontal divs. My problem is that the first one has a thicker border than all the others, which now have a small gap between them and the header.

CSS:

```
.seperate{
    background-image: url("midnight.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100px;
}
.container{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    height:600px;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;    
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
test
</div><!--

--><div class="seperate">
</div>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hgpkbqg5/1/

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Well, you are applying a border to **all** division elements. Since the first element is wrapped in another div, of course it will have double thick borders. The rest do not because the parent div has a fixed dimensions which means its borders will not extend to wrap all remaining elements.

Comment: @Terry Thank you for explaining that. I just started learning about this a week ago and I don't understand a lot of that kind of stuff yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,

```
.seperate{
  background-image: url("midnight.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100px;
}
.container{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  height:600px;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;    
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

css for div will affects all divs in the page including container

Comment: is the issue fixed?